# orderBy not working with customOrder in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

On view page, I have used filter like this :

> ```
>  <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="product in vendorProducts.offers | orderBy:customOrder" ng-if="vendorProducts.offers.length > 0">
> ```

In controller, I have created custom filter :

```
 $scope.customOrder = function (item) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.cRoomProducts, function(cRoomProduct) {
      var vproduct = _.find($scope.vendorProducts.offers,function(vp){ return vp._id == cRoomProduct.offerDetails[0]._id })
      filtered.push(vproduct)
    });

    var remainOfferProduct = $scope.vendorProducts.offers.filter(function(x) { return filtered.indexOf(x) < 0 })
    filtered = filtered.concat(remainOfferProduct)
    return filtered;
     };
```

getting array in **filtered** but still data is not sorted.
Any help on this highly appreciated.

I have two arrays. I want to sort data by using data of first array comes first. $scope.cRoomProducts data comes first So, I have filtered data accordingly. and want to sort data of vendorProducts.offers .

Comment: `filtered` contains `vendorProducts.offers` items sorted ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai. Yes filtered contains array of sorted items of vendorProducts.offers

Comment: What's the name of field you want to sort by ?

Comment: At the end of function, `filtered` array contains boolean values, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
ng-repeat="product in vendorProducts.offers | filter:customOrder"
```